# Small LineageOS phone, either cheap or rugged

Tags: android, smartphones

I'm searching for a phone which meets those requirements:

- Either below $100, or rugged (that is, I want to minimize cost of use. And I tend to drop things)
- No larger than 4.5", but the smaller the better
- Supported by current LineageOS (used to be named Cyanogenmod)
- 4G
- Removable storage, i.e. uSD

While there are other requirements, I don't think there can be a candidate which meets the ones I listed, but not the ones I didn't list.

Comment: In my experience Lineage OS sucks pretty much on anything but official Google phones.  The drivers are not open source but binary blobs for many phones even by Samsung and are not forward/backwards compatible.  So I do not believe a phone like this exists.  Despite phones operating systems being open source the hardware isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Lineage OS has been ported to the AGM A8 rugged phone which goes for around 160 USD.

http://www.agmmobile.com/en/news/now-AGM-A8-gets-Lineage-OS

Comment: Although the form factor is five inch.

Comment: That looks perfect... but I can not find an actual (source) download and a single binary download is not enough to base a decision to buy something on - (where) do I get updates, does it even work, etc. I don't think this counts as "supported by current LineageOS" unless you can add a link to a source repo.

Comment: That press release was three years old. Press releases are wonderful things; when they show a contact; this did not. However, you could write agm@agmmobile.com and see if you get a response when you ask for source code.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a phone both =< 4.5" and < $100 currently supported for LineageOS, nor could I find one described as 'rugged'.

The smallest found, at 4.7", is the [Samsung Galaxy A3](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/a3xelte) in the [$80 and up range](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1536&bih=722&tbm=shop&q=%22Samsung%20Galaxy%20A3%22&tbs=vw%3Al%2Cmr%3A1%2Cp_ord%3Ap%2Cprice%3A1%2Cppr_min%3A80%2Cppr_max%3A100&ei=9N-VXqGsN8a30PEPmrSDqAQ&ved=0ahUKEwih9rrEpujoAhXGGzQIHRraAEUQuisIhgMoAQ).

Several were available in the 5.1"-5.2" (diagonal) size range:

A refurbished [ASUS Zenphone 3](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/zenfone3) is available [FOB Destination for $102](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/6074498862042786720).

A 'certified' refurbuished [Google Pixel](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/sailfish) can be found for [$51 shipped](https://uptradeit.com/buy/google-pixel?variant=33562349MW).

The LeEco Le 2 (not refurbished) is [$86 from multiple eBay vendors](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&psb=1&x=0&y=0&q=LeEco%20Le%202&oq=LeEco%20Le%202&aqs=products-cc..0l10) and [$98 from AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000323193117.html).

The [LG G2](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/d802) is [$78 from eBay vendors](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/d802) and [AliExpress vendors](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000317466804.html).